# Android preferences screen with interdependent entries

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have an Android preferences screen where some of the preferences are interdependent.

In other words, if one of the preferences is set to a certain value(s) then another two of the others are available.
If not, then they are not because they are meaningless.

Specifically, I have an option with 3 possible values: Prompt, Yes and No.
When the value is set to No I want to lock the other 2 options.

How do I do this in Android 2.1?

Comment: NOTE: The question as originally posed two hours ago is incorrect. In discussion on a now-deleted answer, the OP has indicated that the "base" preference is *not* a "check box", but something else (presumably a `ListPreference`) with "3 possible states" (prompt, always, never), and wants the dependent preferences disabled when the base is set to "never".

Comment: My mistake. Sorry about that. Edited to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just call `setEnabled()` on the preferences you want to enable/disable in the OnPreferenceChangeListener for the 3-way preference.  e.g.:

```
otherPrefOne = (ListPreference)findPreference("OTHER_PREF_1");
otherPrefTwo = (ListPreference)findPreference("OTHER_PREF_2");

ThreeWayPref = (ListPreference)findPreference("3WAY_PREF");
ThreeWayPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        if (((String)newValue).equals("No")) {
            otherPrefOne.setEnabled(false);
            otherPrefTwo.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            otherPrefOne.setEnabled(true);
            otherPrefTwo.setEnabled(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```